# Upload .txt file and insert contents into a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, text, text-files

I am trying to grab the contents of a text file, verify that there are 60,000 characters or less, and insert that into a database.  If there are more than 60,000 characters it should be truncated.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Oh, and after the file has been inserted into the database (or fails to do so) the text file should be deleted.

Comment: file_get_contnets, strlen, then the usual db insert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

// db connection here

// set path of uploaded file
$path = "./".basename($_FILES['filename']['name']); 

// move file to current directory
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $path)) {

// get file contents
$data = file_get_contents($path, NULL, NULL, 0, 60000);

// run the query
@mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('".$data."')");

// delete the file
unlink($path);

?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="POST">
  <input name="filename" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="upload file" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is the text file stored on my server?  If so, how do I delete it?

Comment: Did you look at the code? I've even commented it for you and theres a comment saying "delete the file"..

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to check the length first. The truncation can be done implicitely:

```
$content = file_get_contents("asciiart.txt");
$content = substr($content, 0, 60000);
```

This works because `substr` only cuts off the string if it is really longer. Otherwise it will just keep it. The database insert should pose no problems then:

```
$pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO textfiles (content) VALUES (?)")
    ->execute(array($content));
```

Comment: you can specify a max length in `file_get_contents()`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if you get syntax errors I'm on my iPad.

```
<?php
$txt = $_FILES['files'];
$dbTxt = mysql_real_escape_string($txt);
if((!strlen($txt) =< 60000) && ($txt['type'] == "text/plain")) {
    die("Error here");
}
// no need for else as txt above 60000 have been locked away
move_uploaded_file($txt['temp_name'], 'tmp/'.$_server['remote_addr']);
$contents = file_get_contents('tmp/'.$_server['remote_addr']);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO txtUpload(text, ip) VALUES ($contents, $_server['remote_addr']");


$myFile = ''tmp/'.$_server['remote_addr'];
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fclose($fh);
Unlink($myFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function bulk_upload()
    {
        $output = array();
       

        $file_upload    = $_FILES['bulk_karvy_file']['tmp_name'];

        if (isset($file_upload) && !empty($file_upload)){ 

            //You can add directly the Composer Autoloder in your controller: 
            require FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';

            try{   
                $db_spreadsheet = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file_upload);   
            }   
            catch (Exception $e){
                die('Error loading file "' . pathinfo($file_upload, PATHINFO_BASENAME) . '": '.@$e->getMessage()); 
            }   

            // sheet list
            $sheetListArray = ["Ann B","Ann C","Ann E","Ann F"];

            $sheetData = [];
            
            $sheetCount = $db_spreadsheet->getSheetCount(); 

            if(is_null($sheetCount))
            {
                $output['db_msg']       = "Invalid File.";
                $output['db_status']    = true;
            }
            else{

                $db_flag = 0;

                // Read Excel Sheet
                for ($i = 0; $i < $sheetCount; $i++) 
                {
                    $sheet  = $db_spreadsheet->getSheet($i);
                    $sheetN = $sheet->getTitle();

                    if(in_array($sheetN,$sheetListArray))
                    {
                        $sheetData[] = array(
                            'data'    => $sheet->toArray(null, true, true, true),
                            'file'    => $sheetN,
                            'total'   => count($sheet->toArray(null, true, true, true))
                        );
                 
                    }else{
                        $output['db_msg']       = "Invalid Sheet Name. Eg.: ANN_C";
                        $output['db_status']    = true;
                    }

                
                }

                // Read all Sheets from your Excel file, you have to use foreach loop
                foreach($sheetData as $val)
                {
                    $N = @$val['total'];  
                    
                    $db_fn = $this->krObject->getFileNameId(trim('ANN_'.substr($val['file'],4,1)));

                    if(is_null($db_fn))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
    
                    for($i=2; $i <= $N; $i++) {
                    
                        $db_ch= 64;        

                        $sl_no          = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        if(empty($sl_no)){break;}
                        $ref_no         = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $remark         = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $dep_slip_no    = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $inst_no        = str_pad(trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]),6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                        $amount         = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $drawee_name    = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $sch_code       = str_pad(trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]),3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
                        $ufc_code       = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $acc_no         = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $ihno           = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $trno           = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $tr_dt          = str_replace('/', '-',trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]));
                        $value_date     = str_replace('/', '-',trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]));
                        $branch         = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $file_name      = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $category       = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $upload_type    = trim($val['data'][$i][chr(++$db_ch)]);
                        $fl_name        = @$db_fn->file_name;
                        $fl_name_id     = @$db_fn->id;
                        $created_at     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                        $updated_at     = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");   

                        $insertKarvyData     = array(
                            'sl_no'          => $sl_no,
                            'ref_no'         => $ref_no,
                            'remark'         => $remark,
                            'dep_slip_no'    => $dep_slip_no,
                            'inst_no'        => $inst_no,
                            'amount'         => $amount,
                            'drawee_name'    => $drawee_name,
                            'sch_code'       => $sch_code,
                            'ufc_code'       => $ufc_code,
                            'acc_no'         => $acc_no,
                            'ihno'           => $ihno,
                            'trno'           => $trno,
                            'tr_dt'          => (empty($tr_dt))? null:date("Y-m-d",strtotime($tr_dt)),
                            'value_date'     => (empty($value_date))? null:date("Y-m-d",strtotime($tr_dt)),
                            'branch'         => $branch,
                            'file_name'      => $file_name,
                            'category'       => $category,
                            'upload_type'    => $upload_type,
                            'fl_name'        => $fl_name,
                            'fl_name_id'     => $fl_name_id,
                            'created_at'     => $created_at,
                            'updated_at'     => $updated_at 
                        );

                        if($this->krObject->insertKarvyData($insertKarvyData))
                        {
                            ++$db_flag;
                        } 
                        
                    } // Inner loop end

                } // Outer loop end

                $output['db_msg']       = "success";
                $output['db_status']    = false;

            } // end of else

            

            
        }

        echo json_encode($output);
    }
```